# How to ignore one router for BasicAuth check with Echo framework?

Tags: go, frameworks, router, basic-authentication

In order to use basic auth to protect the whole application this way can do for all the routers:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/subtle"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

type Message struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func(username, password string, c echo.Context) (bool, error) {
        if subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(username), []byte("username")) == 1 &&
            subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(password), []byte("password")) == 1 {
            return true, nil
        }
        return false, nil
    }))

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })

    e.GET("/hello", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello")
    })

    e.GET("/healthcheck", func(c echo.Context) error {
        u := &Message{
            Status: "OK",
        }
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, u)
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}
```

If want to ignore one router -- `/healthcheck` to its target, how to do?

If set `e.Use(middleware.BasicAuth)` to each router except /healthcheck will resolve the issue, but it needs to many codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`Group`](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/routing#group) routes

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/subtle"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

type Message struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    g := e.Group("/")
    g.Use(middleware.BasicAuth(func(username, password string, c echo.Context) (bool, error) {
        if subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(username), []byte("username")) == 1 &&
            subtle.ConstantTimeCompare([]byte(password), []byte("password")) == 1 {
            return true, nil
        }
        return false, nil
    }))

    g.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })

    e.GET("/healthcheck", func(c echo.Context) error {
        u := &Message{
            Status: "OK",
        }
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, u)
    })
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}
```

Comment: But if have multiple other routers, how to set group?

Comment: add your route to the group... its here in the example.

Comment: In the question, I added a `/hello` router. I can't add both `/` and `/hello` to one group: g := e.Group("/", "/hello").

Comment: Oh, `g.GET`. Thank you.